# Using regular expressions in c#

Tags: c#, regex

Following is the source:

```
 <option value="ON">Ontario
 <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island
```

I want to return a List or array of strings in the following format:

```
 s(0) = "ON,Ontario" 
 s(1) = "PE,Prince Edward Island"
```

How to create a function to return this `List<string>`

Comment: I tried my best to make it a little less gibberish :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have an XML file and would like to retrieve information from nodes (attributes and contents).

See MSDN Documentation on [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Regular expressions would *not* be ideal for this purpose.

EDIT: Now it looks like you want info from a DropDownList from an aspx page.
To do that, you need:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach(ListItem li in DropDownListID.Items)
{
    string value = li.Value.ToString();
    string text = li.Text;
    list.Add(string.Concat(value, ", ", text));
}
```

Comment: That's not valid XML. I don't think an XML parser will be of any use. It is valid HTML, though.